# REST Api and websocket in the same project?

Tags: spring-boot, rest, websocket

I have never used websocket before and i have no idea if I can use both REST Api for normal crud requests and websocket for many real time charts and data in the same spring application,
my question is, can I use both dependencies **spring-starter-web** and **spring-starter-websocket** because I haven't seen a tutorial where they used both , or will it cause conflicts.

Comment: Yes, you can use both

Comment: so i can use both dependencies and add seperate controllers using the websocket and they will both work perfectly

Comment: Yes. The `@Controller` annotation doesn't mean anything by itself. It just indicates that a class is a web controller and nothing more. Usually, the `@Controller` annotation is used together with `@RequestMapping`, but it doesn't require to be. You can have a `@Controller` annotated class which deals with your REST API requests and another which deals with messages within websockets

Comment: Yes you can. For websocket example https://github.com/GnanaJeyam/WebSocket